# PLACES API: Address returned by maps.google.com different from when invoked via API

Tags: google-maps

When I pass the address to Google Maps .com in the browser, it returns a certain name of the address on the marker(as shown in fig -1). But when I pass the postal address using Google Place and Geocoder API’s, it returns me the address and place ID with the marker(as shown in fig-2) .

As shown in images the address values returned by MAPS application is different from the one’s I am getting through the API’s.

Is it some attribute of the API which gives the name of the building or centre situated at this address?

Is it some premium service that I need to buy in order to display the exact name of building at this address ?

I have tried with various attributes of the PLACES API but not getting the value I need.   [using PLACE API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARLQ4.png)

```
var address = "1900 S Jackson Rd Suite 7 MCALLEN TX";
          var map;
          var marker;
          var service;
          var request;

          function initialize() {
              var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), 
              {
                  center :  {
                      lat :  - 33.866, lng : 151.196
                  },
                  zoom : 15
              });
              if (geocoder) {
                  geocoder.geocode( {
                      'address' : address
                  },
                  function (results, status) {
                      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                          if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                              service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
                              console.log(results[0].place_id);
                              map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                              console.log('resulta ddre '+results[0].formatted_address);
                              service.getDetails( {
                                  placeId : (results[0].place_id)
                              },
                              function (place, status) {
                                  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                                  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                                     console.log(status);
                                      marker = new google.maps.Marker( {
                                          map : map, position : place.geometry.location
                                      });
                                      console.log('<HTML ATT>'+ place.address_components+'Place ID: ' + place.place_id 
                                      +  '<Place Name>' + place.name 
                                      + '<Formatted Address>' + place.formatted_address);
                                      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {                                        
                                          infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + 'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' + place.formatted_address + 
'</div>');
                                          infowindow.open(map, this);
                                      });
                                  }
                              });

                          };

                      }
                  });
              }
          }
```

Comment: where are your images?

Answer (score 0):

When you search "1900 S Jackson Rd Suite 7 MCALLEN TX" on maps.google.com you get the location of "Pediatric Lung Center: Ayres Roberto A MD".

Please note that Geocoding service works only with street addresses, and businesses are excluded from the search. In your code you execute a geocoding request first so you get a different result. You have to execute places text search to get the same business as on maps.google.com.

Have a look at the following example:

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var infowindow;
var address = "1900 S Jackson Rd Suite 7 MCALLEN TX";

function initMap() {
    var m_center = {lat: 26.1817228, lng: -98.2098557};

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: m_center,
      zoom: 16
    });

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.textSearch({
      query: address,
      bounds: map.getBounds()
    }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
}

function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location,
      title: place.name
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
```